# How do I calculate inner product of two vectors in nalgebra?

Tags: matrix, vector, rust, nalgebra

From the following

```
let v = OVector::<f64, U2>::from_column_slice(&[3_f64, 4_f64]);
let x = &v.transpose() * &v;        // get the inner product, i.e. <v,v>
```

I expected `x` to be a `f64` scalar, i.e. `x = 25.0`.

But actually, I can only obtain `x` as `OMatrix::<f64, Cosnt<1>, Const<1>>`.

The case can be even worse in matrix product operations. for example, the following code doesn't work since  `v^T v` is not a scalar.

```
let m = OMatrix::<f64, U2, U2>::from_element(1.0);
let v = OVector::<f64, U2>::from_column_slice(&[3_f64, 4_f64]);

// not working
let y = &v.transpose() * &v * m;        // types conflict 

// working
let y = 25.0 * m;                       // expected to behave like this
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in maths, you would identify 1x1 matrices with scalars (because, for some definition of being equivalent, they are equivalent...). When doing this, the dot product of two vectors is exactly the dot product between two matrices, when we see vectors as matrix columns (which are also equivalent for some equivalence...).

However, here, it is not the case: Rust has to know what is the type of the data. So, I would suggest, since you are using matrices to start with, to use the actual matrix dot product, not the vector one. It's simply `(v.transpose()*v).trace()`. This is a more general dot product, but notice taking the trace will exactly "extract" the scalar from the 1x1 matrix.

Otherwise, this operation is already defined as the `dot` product (unsurprisingly): `v.dot(v)`.

Comment: Thanks for your guideline. Does that mean the user should make clear of where each 1x1 matrix would occur exactly in compile time? and is there any automation tricks provided by `nalgebra` that helps transforming 1x1 matrix into scalar when necessary?

Comment: @xcwang unfortunately, I've never used nalgebra before, I just read the documentation to find the functions I mentioned. All I know is that, for Rust, a 1x1 matrix is not the same as a scalar: you have to make an explicit conversion. However, I think that most of the time, even in maths, you would not need to identify 1x1 matrices with scalars: most operations already provide scalars when you need them, such as `v.dot(v)`.

Comment: thanks, I agree with most of that. I still don't understand the existence necessity of 1x1 matric, though we can make a workaround.

Comment: @xcwang I don't understand what you don't understand. Assume you don't know at compile time the size of your matrices. Then the result of matrix multiplication **must** be a matrix. Even if at runtime it happens to be a 1x1 matrix. This is not about matrices; it's really about Rust's type system (indeed, in maths, you make no differences between 1x1 matrices and scalars).

Comment: assume I have a composition of products (e.g. A*B*C*D*E) to calculate, I expect a single-line code like `let z = A * B * C * D * E ;` , but as the workaround, I have to write multi-line code to do this like `let x = A * B * C * D; let y = x.trace(); let z = y * E ;` As an alternative, since 1x1 matrices only make sense inside the crate but not outside, I just don't understand why not translate it to a scalar automatically as soon as it happens.

Comment: but after this discussion, I start to understand that the current workaround is indeed acceptable. It seems that we could always be aware of the positions where 1x1 matrices would happen prior to the program running. Therefore, we can split the composition of multiplication into several parts and turn each 1x1 matrix into a scalar manually, and then use the scalar to continue the remaining multiplication. In other words, it is impossible for a 1x1 matrix to happen beyond we can expect, isn't it?

Comment: @xcwang The fact is that there are three distinct products: the matrix (inner) product, the dot product and the scalar product. Turns out that, my a coincidence, sometimes the matrix product can produce 1x1 matrix that could be identified with the scalar produced by the dot product. You exploit that because in your case these two product produce the same result, up to a trivial isomorphism between scalars and 1x1 matrices. In maths, that would be OK. For Rust, it is not because Rust is more strict due to its type system.

Comment: This means that it's not a "workaround" to just use the dot product instead of the matrix product: what you wanted from the beginning was the dot product, and when writing maths equations it's usually ok to write the matrix product instead of the dot product, when we know the result will be a 1x1 matrix.